# $f : (Ω, \mathscr{A}) \to \Bbb R \cup \{\pm \infty \}$ ,does $f$ being constant on each atom $A$ of $\mathscr{A}$ imply $f$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

> (**EDIT:**) Definition of Atom considered for this problem: A set $A$ in $(Ω, \mathscr{A})$ is Atom if $A \in \mathscr{A}$, but no non-empty proper
>   subset of $A$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}$.
>
> (a) Show that if $f : (Ω, \mathscr{A}) \to \Bbb R \cup \{\pm \infty \}$ is a measurable function, then $f$ must be constant on each atom $A$ of $\mathscr{A}$.(b) Is the converse true ?

My attempt:

(a) For the sake of contradiction let us assume that $\exists A \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $f$ is not constant on $A$ i.e. $\exists A_1 \subset A$ such that $f(A_1) =c $ and $f(A- A_1) \ne c$. But then, $A_1 = f^{-1}(c) \cap A \in \mathscr{A}$ , contradicting the fact that $A$ is an atom of $\mathscr{A}$.

(b) If I am able to show that pre-image of a generating class of the Borel sigma algebra under $f$ is in $\mathscr{A}$, then the converse is also true. But how to proceed?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What are the atoms of the Lebsegue measure?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path real singletons

Comment: @SaucyO'Path do you mean that if pre-image of Atoms are atoms, then the function is measurable!

Comment: No, wait: singletons *are not* atoms of the Lebesgue measure. This makes it much easier.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path my question basically works with only Borel sigma field and no need to go to Lebesgue

Comment: What is the definition of atom in your context? It often refers to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)), and I suspect that this is not the definition you are seeking considering that you are not mentioning any measure...

Comment: @SangchulLee I've Edited question and have mentioned the definition I'm working with.

Comment: Given the definition, the atoms of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ are exactly singletons, and it seems to me that they have no power to distinguish measurable functions from non-measurable functions...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interpreting the converse wrongly.The converse simply says that if every measurable function is constant on $A$ then $A$ is necessarily an atom. This is quite obvious: if $B$ is a proper non-empty subset of $A$ belonging to $\mathcal A$ then $I_B$ is  a measurable function which takes both the values $0$ and $1$ on $A$. So we have a contradiction.  [Def.: $I_B(x)=1$ if $x \in B$, $0$ otherwise]. Incidentally, the answer to the question in title is no; the atoms of the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb R$ are the singletons and every map is constant on singletons. Not every map is measurable. This makes it clear that you interpretation of the converse is wrong.